# Bloomberg & R: Accessing multiple securities with getBars() in R

Tags: equities, r, programming, bloomberg

I am attempting to access 1 minute trade data for 50 securities using Bloomberg API (rblpapi). Following is the code I got from the CRAN:

```
con <- blpConnect() 
security<- "NIFTY Index" 
field<- "INDX_MEMBERS"sec<- bds( security, field) 
getBars("XYZ IS EQUITY", eventType = "TRADE", barInterval = 01, 
        startTime = Sys.time() - 1360 * 60 * 6, endTime = Sys.time(),
        options = NULL, verbose = FALSE, returnAs = getOption("blpType","matrix"), 
tz= Sys.getenv("TZ", unset = "UTC"))
```

I want to access all 50 securities without repeating my code. Is there a way to directly call a list of member securities of an index from Bloomberg and use it to access intraday data in one go. Also, when I input specific dates such as:

```
getBars("XYZ IS EQUITY", eventType = "TRADE", barInterval = 01,
    startTime = as.Date("2014-01-01 03:30:00"), endTime = as.Date(" 2014-02-04 09:30:00"),
    options = NULL, verbose = FALSE, returnAs = getOption("blpType",
                                                          "matrix"), tz = Sys.getenv("TZ", unset = "UTC"))
```

it shows:

```
Error: startTime and endTime must be Datetime objects
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the As.date documentation (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.Date.html): "Arguments:
x  

An object to be converted.
format  

A character string. If not specified, it will try "%Y-%m-%d" then "%Y/%m/%d" on the first non-NA element, and give an error if neither works. Otherwise, the processing is via strptime"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly:

1. Some functions simply are not vectorised.  If you want to loop `getBars()` over a vector of symbols, write another wrapper doing the looping.
2. As our documentation says: *startTime: A Datetime object with the start time, defaults to one hour before current time* (and ditto for endTime) you need to supply a DateTime object, and `as.POSIXct()` is one way of doing it.  Sticking date and time into `as.Date()` is not.

Comment: I Will try to write the wrapper.